# How properly run and use Docker in Azure Devops Pipelines?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, cicd

I tried do run a docker in pipeline ,first i tried to use documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#troubleshooting but still got errors

Its looks like my pipeline properly download a docker file but when i try to exec any command in docker file i got errors

```
steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: true
      fetchDepth: full

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Login to ACR
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'Docker'
        command: 'login'
    
    - script: |
        docker run -d docker.io/Docker/Sample-docker-image
      displayName: 'Run Docker'

    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'Docker'
        command: 'start'
        container: 'Docker/Sample-docker-image'
```

when i run this i got

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: ***/Docker/Sample-docker-image
Error: failed to start containers: ***/Docker/Sample-docker-image
##[error]Error response from daemon: No such container: ***/Docker/Sample-docker-image
##[error]Error: failed to start containers: ***/Docker/Sample-docker-image
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

How to handle and properly use a docker ? Im doing something wrong in this yml ?

Edit:
i added

```
        container_id=$(docker run -d Docker/Sample-docker-image)
        echo "Container ID: $container_id"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=container_id]$container_id"
        container_id=$(echo $container_id)
       
        while [[ "$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Status}}' $container_id)" != "running" ]]; do
          docker inspect $container_id
          docker logs $container_id
          sleep 10
          docker ps -a
        done
```

and it shows docker starts as exited status. i tried locally and every image works as expected

Comment: are you trying to build and push the docker container to ACR or do you want to execute any command on the docker image?

Comment: I want to execute a command on docker image

Comment: `docker.io/Docker/Sample-docker-image` is not a valid image name. Image names must be lower case.

Comment: @Cezu, check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answers. I made mistake only thing which i missed is a letter -t

```
docker run -t -d --name my-container
```

This solved a issue, container is running and im able to run docker exec

Answer (score 0):

**Below are the steps to execute a command on the docker image.**

**Step 1:** Create a service connection to the container registry if it is private. For public registries, a service connection is not required.
[image]

**Step 2:** Specify the container in the resources section of the pipeline and add the service connection name as the endpoint as shown below.

```
resources:
 containers:
   - container: acr-customimg
     image: cleveracr.azurecr.io/customimg:latest
     endpoint: ACR-endpoint
```

**Step 3:** Add the container resource as the target to the steps you would like to execute on the docker container.

```
- script: echo hostname
  displayName: 'run script in docker container'
  target: 
   container: acr-customimg
```

Below is the full pipeline code.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
 containers:
   - container: acr-customimg
     image: cleveracr.azurecr.io/customimg:latest
     endpoint: ACR-endpoint

steps:
- script: echo hostname
  displayName: 'run script in azure agent'

- script: echo hostname
  displayName: 'run script in docker container'
  target: 
   container: acr-customimg
```

When I run this pipeline, it first [fetches the image from the container registry](https://i.imgur.com/JacSqST.png) and then start the container. The first step will execute on the [azure agent](https://i.imgur.com/MSgwm2a.png) while the second step will execute on the [docker container](https://i.imgur.com/QCOFDD3.png).

**References:**

1. [Define container jobs | Microsoft doccumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops)
2. [Step target | Microsoft doccumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#step-target)